# Firebase Cloud Firestore - How to derive and store the percentage of a user's rank as a top buyer

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to build a simple e-commerce application that lets users buy different digital products. I also want to track every user's total purchase value and get their percentage as a top buyer (Basically ranking based on total money spent).

So a user who spent a total of $50k would have a **lower** percentage as a top buyer than someone who spent a total of $100.

This is just like OnlyFans, how creators can showcase their percentage as top creators.

Question: How would I derive and store this data in Cloud Firestore, I can easily get the total amount spent by a user but to get their percentage is a bit tricky.

My Opinion: I could simply create a cron job that runs every week or month and would calculate and update every user's rank but I feel that would be expensive if the app scales and cloud Firestore's transactions are limited to 500 writes.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore so we can see how you are storing the data? and then explain what % you are looking for?

Comment: I have a user collection that points to a particular user. That stores basic info of a user like name, age, etc. It also holds the total_amount_spent which is a double (number). I want to add another field that contains the rank (Based on total_amount_spent) of a user and also another field that is the percentage of the user's rank.

Comment: @Dharmaraj in your StackOverflow profile everyone can see you are in the top 0.03% this year. That's exactly what I want to replicate in my app. In my case, you will be the top 0.03% spender.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned with write count, I strongly believe you should have just *one*  object in Firestore that contains a hashtable of everyone's rank:

```json
{
   "userId": 0.03,
   "userId2": 0.034,
   "userId3": 0.100
}
```

Either when a transaction occurs, or as a separate process outside of the context of a transaction, run a process that reads everyone's spending, and recalculate the rank, and update this hashtable with the new ranks.

If you only update this document periodically, also consider caching the ranks so that your application doesn't have to go back to Firestore to get the new data.

If you are considered with read count, you could create a second hashtable of users and their spending, instead of inside of each client record:

```json
{
   "userId1": 20000,
   "userId2": 23000,
   "userId3": 21000
}
```

You should be able to perform a merge update to just update the content with just the hash table entry you need to update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the percentage of a user, then I think that is more appropriate to store that data in the Realtime Database rather than in Firestore. Or maybe you can store the total a user has spent, and then calculate the percentage in your application code.

It's true, you can create a document that can hold all those percentages or the total spent, but please note that you're [limited to 1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). So the Realtime Database schema might look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- ranks
        |
        --- $uid: 50000
        |
        --- $uid: 100
```

Now, each time a user buys something simply increment the value using:

```
FieldValue.increment(Int64(purchase))
```

Here are the Swift API docs for [FieldValue.increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue#increment_:) and the [Firebase official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

So in this case, there is nothing you need to pay when you update that number. You'll only have to pay when you read that value. So in my opinion, there is no need to create a cron job. However, if you need to schedule some operations in Realtime Database, you can consider using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/), which allows you to schedule HTTP requests or Cloud Pub/Sub messages to the [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) that you deploy.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your response. Storing the user's total_spent is the easy part; what you stated above works perfectly. I also want to store their percentage as a top spender in Firestore or Realtime Database.

Comment: Then store that percentage in the same way you do for the total.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Wouldn't calculating the percentage client side be way more expensive, I would have to read all user documents for every single session plus that may also be a security issue since the total_spent is a sensitive data.

Comment: The issue is that the total is easier to derive since it's just an increment function. To derive a user's percentage I need to get their rank and the overall number of users in the app.

To get a user's rank, I need to sort each user by total_amount_spent in descending order.

Comment: That's not an option to read all documents in order to calculate a percentage. You should add the percentage in the Realtime Database, or as a field in a document in Firestore, and modify it every time a new order is placed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247802/discussion-between-rezia-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Did my latest solution help?